# html to pdf is taking way longer than html to word

Tags: pdf, ms-word, pdf-generation

So I am trying downloading a 260 / 270 pages document, which is a little over 1 mb when downloaded as a document. When downloaded as a word document, it takes about a second, however, when trying to download the same as a PDF, it is taking an eternity.

Any idea why this is happenning, can the number of pages be a reason, and if so, any solution here?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say enough about the context you're in - language, libraries, tools or whatever - to give a good answer.

However, I'd guess that the PDF is being generated as images, not as text, and so the massive increase in file size (assuming that is what you mean by taking an eternity).

If you have control of the environment - use a better tool/library to render the PDF. PDF is perfectly capable of rendering text and graphics as such. If you don't control it, either complain to the vendor or make a cup of tea!